# Get list of Users and comment made by them (Django Serializers)

Tags: django, python-3.x, api

Have Users Table (with fields id, name) and Comments Table (Comment, CreatedBy (integer) - which is user id).

How can i write a serialiser to fetch the list of users, that should contain the array of comments created by each user.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
          model = Users
          fields = ('id','name')

class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
          model = UserComments
          fields = ('id','comment','created_by')
```

Expecting the below output:

```
[
       {
          "id":1,
          "name":"Tony",
          "comments":[
             {
                "id":1,
                "comment":"This is a test comment"
             },
             {
                "id":2,
                "comment":"This is a test comment2"
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "id":2,
          "name":"Alaric",
          "comments":[
             {
                "id":3,
                "comment":"This is a test comment3"
             },
             {
                "id":4,
                "comment":"This is a test comment4"
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

Comment: [Nested relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Comment: @DanielRoseman issue is, the model doesn't have foreign key relation.

Comment: Well why not? If CreatedBy is an integer which represents a user ID, why not declare it as a foreign key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way for this would be using a ForeignKey relation and nested serializers, but if for some reason you can not declare a foreign key relationship between **UserComments** and **Users**, you can use **SerializerMethodField**s:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
         model = Users
         fields = ('id','name', 'comments')

    def get_comments(self, obj):
        return CommentSerializer(UserComments.objects.filter(created_by=obj.id), many=True).data
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @Ozgur Akcali

Comment: @MadhuP I've updated my answer, you also need to add comments on fields list in meta class